# prettyDate time is off by 1 day

Tags: javascript, date, time

Using the original John Resig prettyDate script [here](http://ejohn.org/files/pretty.js)

Problem: Australia here date is 29/9/2014 or 9/29/2014 format if your in the US

I feed prettyDate this time format:

```
prettyDate("2014-09-27T06:24:17Z")
```

It returns:

```
Yesterday
```

it should say "2 days ago"

What's wrong why is it off by 1 day?

also if I feed it the 29th 6am this morning:

```
prettyDate("2014-09-29T06:00:17Z")
```

It returns nothing just blank.
Here is the code can anyone figure this out? And yes the date in my system tray clock is set on the 29/9/2014.

```
    function prettyDate(time){
    var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
        diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 )
        return;

    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && "just now" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago";
}

// If jQuery is included in the page, adds a jQuery plugin to handle it as well
if ( typeof jQuery != "undefined" )
    jQuery.fn.prettyDate = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var date = prettyDate(this.title);
            if ( date )
                jQuery(this).text( date );
        });
    };
```

Comment: that shouldn't be too hard to debug, just log what `(((new Date()).getTime()` and `date.getTime()` claim?

Comment: At what time did you test this? 1 hour ago, or before 06:24 this morning? If it is the latter then it was < 2 days ago + for the second case you would get a negative value for `diff`, hence `return` after test on `day_diff < 0`.

Comment: a right okay, i think I get it now. But I'm referring to a day as in day of the week not by 24 hours. Yeah this is confusing.

Comment: a right okay, i think I get it now. But I'm referring to a day as in day of the week not by 24 hours. Yeah this is confusing. It's still not right because if it's 14:30 and time was stamped at say 22:30, the event still took place yesterday but instead it returns 14 hours ago. I'm trying to get it to say Yesterday Morning or Yesterday Afternoon